# Permision denied when change GPU clock rate in Nvidia Jetson TX1

Tags: linux, nvidia, gpu

I have a Nvidia TX1 development kit which I've installed ubuntu 16.04 using JetPack-L4T-3.1-linux-x64.run (in full installation mode) on it.
The installation procedure are based on the following link: [ http://docs.nvidia.com/jetpack-l4t/2_1/content/developertools/mobile/jetpack/jetpack_l4t/2.0/jetpack_l4t_install.htm ]

I wanted to test its GPU performance for our application but since its clock is set to the minimum value which is 76800000 HZ I can't get enough performance out of it.
I've read in this link [ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41146835/changing-the-gpu-clock-rate-on-a-linux-like-system-nvidia-jetson-tx1 ] how to change the value of GPU when permission denied happens. but none of them works for my linux ! Is there any hope for changing the clock speed of the GPU on this board ?

It is worth mentioning that instead of having this path for changing clock rate
`/sys/kernel/debug/clock/override.gbus/rate`
I have this path:
`/sys/kernel/debug/clk/override.gbus/clk_rate`

So you can see I don't have any clock folder or rate file ! I can see different options for gpu clock rate in this file: `/sys/kernel/debug/clk/gbus/clk_possible_rates`

Comment: What is "none of them works"? Do you get an error? Or just no speed increase?

Comment: for me "none of them works" means `echo: write error: Permission denied` even if I am root (after `sudo -i`). Or `echo 614400 | sudo tee /sys/kernel/debug/clk/override.gbus/clk_rate`

Comment: Answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45779938/permision-denied-when-change-gpu-clock-rate-in-tx1